# redirect output of sql to file in unix

Tags: unix

I need to run a stored proc and redirect its output to a text file. Right now I am using the below command to do it, but in the text file I have the headers and also the columns are separated by spaces. I need the output file to start with the first row of data and no spaces between the columns. Can someone please advise how to do this?

Thanks!

Command:

```
  isql  -S <server>-U <user>-P <password> -w1024 << EOB1 >> <text file>

  use <db_name>
  go
  exec <proc>
  go
 EOB1
```

Comment: What is `isql`? Take a look at its manual to see if there are any flags for changing the output format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I found -b disables headers